# Image Getter in Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I was trying some codes that i found here using the `ImageGetter` to display the image source from an html code. I encountered a problem when my app was trying to get the image from the said html code. This is my first time working with fragments.

This class that I am currently working on extends `Fragment`. I dont know how to cast the Object result which is a `Drawable` object inside the fragment.

And could you also enlighten me about `Fragment`s, Why some codes that work on a normal `Activity` and when you extend a fragment you need to add `getActivity` or `getView`.

It the error points out at the line: Attempt to invoke virtual object on a null reference.

```
urlDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, 0 + result.getIntrinsicWidth(), 0
                        + result.getIntrinsicHeight());
```

Logcat Points the Error on the Code above `result.getIntrinsicWidth()`.

```
 @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Drawable result) {
                // set the correct bound according to the result from HTTP call
                urlDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, 0 + result.getIntrinsicWidth(), 0
                        + result.getIntrinsicHeight());

                // change the reference of the current drawable to the result
                // from the HTTP call
                urlDrawable.drawable = result;

                // redraw the image by invalidating the container
                URLImageParser.this.container.invalidate();
            }
```

Do in BackGround:

```
 @Override
            protected Drawable doInBackground(String... params) {
                String source = params[0];
                return fetchDrawable(source);
            }
```

Whole Class for image getter:

```
 public class ImageGetterAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Drawable> {
            URLDrawable urlDrawable;

            public ImageGetterAsyncTask(URLDrawable d) {
                this.urlDrawable = d;
            }

            @Override
            protected Drawable doInBackground(String... params) {
                String source = params[0];
                return fetchDrawable(source);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Drawable result) {
                // set the correct bound according to the result from HTTP call
                urlDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, 0 + result.getIntrinsicWidth(), 0
                        + result.getIntrinsicHeight());

                // change the reference of the current drawable to the result
                // from the HTTP call
                urlDrawable.drawable = result;

                // redraw the image by invalidating the container
                URLImageParser.this.container.invalidate();
            }

            /***
             * Get the Drawable from URL
             * @param urlString
             * @return
             */
            public Drawable fetchDrawable(String urlString) {
                try {
                    InputStream is = fetch(urlString);
                    Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
                    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, 0 + drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), 0
                            + drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
                    return drawable;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return null;
                }
            }

            private InputStream fetch(String urlString) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet request = new HttpGet(urlString);
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
                return response.getEntity().getContent();
            }
        }
```

Comment: let me see your doInBackground code

Comment: anyone could take a look at this?

Comment: it means your result in the onPostexecute is null, and `getActvity()` returns the the activity the fragment is attached to, you need it because some methods or functions are not implemented in fragment like `Context` `getView()` returns the parent view of the fragment, and you need it to call view functions like `getHeight()`